# How to show stars in google search results

Tags: magento, rating

I have a Magento site and some products have star rating. 
I would like to add these to the google search results like here below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWjv4.gif

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the design of the reviews templates on the product page to include Google Microdata. Read more [about it here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/176035?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks, I just found some nice article about this:  http://www.groovecommerce.com/ecommerce-blog/developers-toolbox-adding-rich-snippets-to-magento-products-with-schema-org-tags/